# ¿Cómo agregar una llave privada y certificado al cliente de un Web Service creando un canal SSL/TLS?

Tags: c#, webservice, certificado-ssl

Cuento con un WSDL el cual, al momento de realizar la solicitud, tanto cliente y servidor utilizan certificados, cuento con un certificado .cer y una llave pública .pfx.

En SOAP UI, solo es necesario la llave pública para realizar la solicitud, pero con el WSDL, el servidor cancela la solicitud o no puede crear un canal SSL/TLS.

```
 ws1.ClientCertificates.AddRange( new X509Certificate[]{ new X509Certificate2(getCertificate("xcertificado")), new X509Certificate2("/xLlavePrivada.pfx","pass"});
```

Además, seguí esta guía para la búsqueda del certificado: [How to call a Web service by using a client certificate for authentication in an ASP.NET Web application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/901183/how-to-call-a-web-service-by-using-a-client-certificate-for-authentication-in-an-asp-net-web-application)

Consigo el certificado desde una colección de certificados, y lo devuelvo.

```
 private static Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509Certificate getCertificate(string certificateName)
    {

        X509CertificateStore certificateStore = X509CertificateStore.CurrentUserStore(X509CertificateStore.RootStore);

        certificateStore.OpenRead();
        writeLog("Store abierto.");
        //Look for the first certificate that is named SecureMathClient.

        //Look in the local machine store.
        Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection collection = certificateStore.FindCertificateBySubjectString(certificateName);
        Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509Certificate certificate = null;
            try
            {
                certificate = collection[0];
                //certificate.

                writeLog("Certificado encontrado: "+ certificate.Subject + ' ' + certificate.FriendlyDisplayName);
                return certificate;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw new Exception("Certificado no encontrado." + e.Message);
            }
    }
```

Pero aun así no puedo crear una conexión segura, ya que al hacer la solicitud lanza la excepción:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Comment: Te faltó poner el enlace de la guía :)

Comment: Gracias. Ya está editado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví. Al agregar los protocolos de seguridad del PointManager.

```
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        writeLog("100-CONTINUE");
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        writeLog("SSL protocol.");
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Además, averigüé que el servicio necesitaba verificación de dos pasos, así que, agregué el ServerCertificateValidationCallback:

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
```

Con ello se logra crear una conexión segura. A pesar de agregar los certificados, verificar el certificado del servidor, se debe de especificar los protocolos de conexión.

Comment: ¿La última sección de código sabes qué es lo que hace? Es un `delegate` que hace la función de un *bypass* para que no tome en cuenta la validación de los certificados y siempre te regresa un `true`, es decir, no se están validando los certificados.

Comment: Si lo sé, para las pruebas es perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se ve, estás usando Services2, yo hace poco tuve un proyecto con Services3. También me pelee con esto como comentas. Resulta que tienes que firmar la petición empleando el certificado.

He realizado un ejemplo con services2 (no lo he probado pero debería funcionar, si falla probablemente tengas que añadir alguna sección dentro de tu .config con services3 tuve que añadir una seccion)

```
//Tu servicio
        Production svc = new Production ();

        byte [] arrayDeBytes = null; //Aqui deberias rellenar con el array de bytes de tu certificado

        //creas un objeto para representar el certificado
        var cert = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509Certificate ( arrayDeBytes );

        //Con esto firmas la petición del certificado
        Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens.SecurityToken securityToken = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityToken ( cert );
        Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.MessageSignature msg = new Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.MessageSignature ( securityToken );

        svc.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add ( securityToken );
        svc.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add ( msg );

        //TODO: llamar al método corresopndiente
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
```

prueba esto.

Pues tienes razón. Lo indicado arriba es para saltarte el paso de validación del certificado y continuar.

Comment: ¿Por qué debería probarlo? Para ser de ayuda, una respuesta con explicaciones será mucho más útil. Dale a [edit] y añade alguna tal y como se sugiere en [answer].